# Is it bad practice to try to focus on an element that doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I basically want to do is to set "if the sibling after `element` has the class `.slct`, I want to focus on it.

Would this be an ok solution:

```
element.next('.slct').focus()
```

Sometimes the next sibling won't have that class.

Comment: I would add an if clause which checks the class on the next sibling. Just in case.

Comment: This would cause an error wouldn't it? Because your calling focus on `undefined`. Why don't you just check if it exists before calling focus (using `.length > 0`)

Comment: It will not cause any error or problem, just this will not focus anything, no big deal. However it can be confusing if from UX perspective element should be focused and nothing will happen.

Comment: doesn't seem to cause any errors...

Comment: It will not cause errors but should always be checked just to avoid unnecessary processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elem = element.next();
if(elem.hasClass('slct')) {
  elem.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check element existence in this way:

```
if(element.next('.slct').length)
     element.next('.slct').focus()
```

Comment: Why do I need to check if the element exists?

Comment: It's not necessary to check element exists. But you asked about **best practice** and I think It's **better** to check element existence before focusing on it.